# Script to match column values and copy data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy-paste values from column W of sheet2 to column AK of sheet1 in case values of colA and colC of sheet1 and sheet2 respectively match

Data sample:

**Sheet1**

```
ColA    
A255    
A355    
A717    
B487
A898
```

**Sheet2**

```
ColC ColW
A898 UK
C787
B487
A355 North America
O888
L151
A255 DACH
A717 UK
```

**Result (Sheet1)**:

```
ColA    ColAK
A255    DACH
A355    North America
A717    UK
B487
A898    UK
```

Would you please advise on the best approach to do this? So far, I didn`t manage to come up with smth that is close to the desired result

Comment: Your text doesn't match your diagrams

Comment: @Cooper, ugh, sorry! corrected the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what Cooper mentioned in the comments, your explanation does not match your sample data. But seeing your data, it makes more sense than the explanation above. So I will make use of the data given.

See script below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh1lastRow = sh1.getLastRow();
  // Sheet1!A:A values
  var sh1AValues = sh1.getRange(1, 1, sh1lastRow, 1).getValues().flat();
  // Sheet1!AK:AK range
  var sh1AKRange = sh1.getRange(1, 37, sh1lastRow, 1);

  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sh2lastRow = sh2.getLastRow();
  // Sheet2!C:C values
  var sh2CValues = sh2.getRange(1, 3, sh2lastRow, 1).getValues().flat();
  // Sheet2!W:W values
  var sh2WValues = sh2.getRange(1, 23, sh2lastRow, 1).getValues().flat();

  // for every values of Sheet1!A:A
  var output = sh1AValues.map(row => {
    // get position of every value in Sheet1!A:A from Sheet2!C:C
    // index is -1 if value is not found
    var index = sh2CValues.indexOf(row);
    // if position is not -1 (means it is found)
    if(index >= 0)
      // return the corresponding value in Sheet2!W:W
      return [sh2WValues[index]];
    // return blank if value in Sheet1!A:A is not found in Sheet2!C:C
    return [];
  });

  // set Sheet1!AK:AK range with value of generated array 
  sh1AKRange.setValues(output);
}
```

#### Sample data:

[image: s1]
[image: s2]

#### Output (Script):

[image: o1]

If it is an option, this is also achievable by using `VLOOKUP` formula which should be simpler to do.

#### Formula:

```
=Arrayformula(if(isblank(A:A), "", VLOOKUP(A:A, {Sheet2!C:C, Sheet2!W:W}, 2, false)))
```

#### Output (Formula):

[image: o2]

Comment: Thanks for looking into my question @Nazia! Indeed, I had a mistake in the description, corrected it now. For some reason, when trying to apply your solution I am getting the following error: Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 1.

Comment: This is the code in question: `,let output = vs1a.map(e => {
    let index = vs2c.indexOf(e);
    if(~index) {return [vs2w[index]];}
    return [];
  });
  rg1w.setValues(output);` did you copy it exactly as he wrote it including the square brackets. It looks correct to me. Although I would have included the brackets around the if just for clarity.  It's about the only way I comment my code.

Comment: You're definitely correct here @Cooper, I don't also see any issue on the code. If copied as a whole and nothing have been done, should be fine. The brackets regarding clarity is actually better but it should not affect the output of the script regardless.

Comment: @KateBedrii, if you can share a sample sheet that the exact f.unction above fails, that would be better for us to clearly fix the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Cooper, I copied the whole script and only changed the sheet names (sh1 = PPR_Active, sh2 = doc) - everything else remained as suggested. Here is a sample data document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10BNrnAyQw89gy-Sj3CLiz4AgVtFI0AjXTvc0REGGTfY/edit#gid=2069903677. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It looks like I accidentally added a typo or smth in the script when I was copying it - re-copied the script and it works now! thank you! Would it be possible to adjust the script so it doesn`t remove the data in column ID2 that is already present on the PPR_Active tab and only add new IDs?

Comment: @KateBedrii, that would be possible but completely different approach from the above answer. I suggest you create another question and note that add only the new ids.